# Optimizing and finding edge cases that I might have missed - 2 coding interview questions

Tags: javascript, recursion

Background - I took an online coding test and was presented with questions similar to this, I did rather poorly on it compared to the hidden grading criteria and I was hoping to get another pair of eyes to look at it and maybe help point out some of my mistakes.

Practice Test questions -

Task: Given an integer inject the number 5 into it to make the largest possible integer
Conditions: (-80000...80000) range needed to handle
Expected input: int
Expected output: int
Testcase: -999 -> -5999
    80 -> 850

```
var lrgInt = function(num) {
    var stringInt = num.toString();
    for (let i = 0; i < stringInt.length; i++) {
        if (stringInt.charAt(i) === "-") {
            return parseInt([stringInt.slice(0, 1), '5', stringInt.slice(1)].join(''));
        }else if (stringInt.charAt(i) < 5) {
             return parseInt([stringInt.slice(0, i), '5', stringInt.slice(i)].join(''));
        }
    }
    return parseInt([stringInt.slice(0, stringInt.length), '5', stringInt.slice(stringInt.length)].join(''));
};
```

Task: Determine the number of operations done on a number following the conditions to reduce it to 0.
Conditions:
 - If the number is odd, subtract 1
 - If the number is even, divide by 2
Expected input: int
Expected output: int

```
var operations = 0;

var numberOfSteps  = function(num) {
    if (num === 0){
        return operations;
    }else if (num % 2 == 0) {
        operations++;
        return numberOfSteps(num/2);
    } else {
        operations++;
        return numberOfSteps(num-1);
    }
};
```

Comment: what means *inject*? do you have some examples for the first question?

Comment: As in insert the number "5" somewhere to make the largest integer possible
  
90 -> 950 / 
2534 -> 52534  /
-999 -> -5999

Answer (score 2):

For the second question, you could add one plus the result of recursion with the adjusted number without having a global counter.

```js
function numberOfSteps(number) {
    if (!number) return 0;
    if (number % 2) return 1 + numberOfSteps(number - 1);
    return 1 + numberOfSteps(number / 2);    
}

console.log(numberOfSteps(5)); // 5 4 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, we make the observation that if the number is positive, we want to inject the 5 before the first digit less than 5, but if it's negative then we want to inject it before the first digit greater than 5. For the second problem, we can just use a simple while loop.

```
function largestNum(num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        // this edge case is weird but I'm assuming this is what they want
        return 50;
    }
    var negative = num < 0;
    var numAsStr = Math.abs(num).toString();
    var inj = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < numAsStr.length; i++) {
        var cur = parseInt(numAsStr[i], 10);
        if ((!negative && cur < 5) || (negative && cur > 5)) {
            // we found a place to inject, break
            inj = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (inj == -1) {
        // didn't inject anywhere so inject at the end
        inj = numAsStr.length;
    }
    return (
        (negative ? -1 : 1) *
        parseInt(numAsStr.substr(0, inj) + "5" + numAsStr.substr(inj))
    );
}

function numSteps(num) {
    var steps = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        if (num % 2) {
            // it's odd
            num--;
        } else {
            num /= 2;
        }
        steps++;
    }
    return steps;
}
```